# Mysql : Join 4 table problem with the result

Tags: mysql

I have 4 table and join with all then i want show data like here :

```
pr_id |nama | jumlah_liker | id_user
1     |Milk |        5     | 1
2     |Choco|        0     | 1
```

Review Table produk

```
pr_id | nama
1     | Milk
2     | Choco
3     | Salad
```

Review Table liker

```
id_produk | id_user
1         | 1 
1         | 1 
1         | 1 
1         | 3 
1         | 2
```

Review Table featured_ukm

```
id | id_produk
1  | 1 
2  | 2
```

But i got sql record

```
id_produk | nama  | jumlah_liker | id_user
1         | milk  | 1            | 1  //problem row i dont get count all record id_produk
2         | choco | 0            | 1

    SELECT produk.*, COUNT(liker.id_produk), liker.id_user
FROM produk 
    left join liker ON liker.id_produk = produk.pr_id AND liker.id_user = 1
    INNER JOIN featured_ukm ON featured_ukm.id_produk = produk.pr_id
    GROUP BY featured_ukm.id_produk
```

Comment: Can you explain why the given result set is not the one you had expected?

Comment: If i remove AND liker.id_user i got what i want but i need check record check from user login

Comment: `SELECT produk.* ... GROUP BY featured_ukm.id_produk` seams to be invalid SQL it's a [very common MySQL error](https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/) .. So common i should marco this comment..

Comment: I need group with the featured_ukm.id_produk

Comment: Your current query can and will result into giving invalid results for every non aggregate columns which are not named in the GROUP. BY.. I advice you to edit the question with the expected output also..

Comment: Please you help me what the solution sir....

Comment: @IrsyadNurilhaq "edit the question with the expected output also"...as Raymond requested. Then it might be easier to help you. Right now your expectation is unclear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Edit: My suggestions are first, I actually put what will produce your exact requested results at the bottom

It appears that you're trying to show how many likes each of the "Featured Product" has.

It isn't entirely clear what you're trying to do with the user id, or what its purpose in the result set is; here is a query to show how many likes each "Featured Product" has:

```
SELECT 
produk.*, 
(SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0)
FROM liker WHERE liker.id_produk = produk.pr_id)
FROM featured_ukm F
INNER JOIN produk ON produk.pr_id = F.id_produk
```

Here is a query to show how many likes each *product* by each user

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
P.*, 
(SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM liker WHERE liker.id_user = L.id_user), 
IFNULL(L.id_user, 0)
FROM produk P
LEFT JOIN liker L ON L.id_produk = P.pr_id
```

and if you want to just see the items that ONE user liked, add:

```
WHERE L.id_user = 1
```

to the end of it.

Here is a query to show how many likes each *Featured Product* has for each user id:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
P.*, 
(SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM liker WHERE liker.id_user = L.id_user), 
IFNULL(L.id_user, 0)
FROM produk P
LEFT JOIN liker L ON L.id_produk = P.pr_id
INNER JOIN featured_ukm F on F.id_produk = P.pr_id
```

To get the exact result set that it would appear that you're looking for (in your example), you will need to reference a user table in your query.  I assume you have one because you're referencing user ids.  For the purpose of this example, I'm creating the below user table.

```
id  |   name
----------------
 1  | user_one
 2  | user_two
 3  | user_three
```

With this table, the following query will give *exactly* what it appears you're looking for:

```
SELECT P.*, (SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM liker WHERE liker.id_produk = 
F.id_produk), user.id
FROM user
CROSS JOIN featured_ukm F
LEFT JOIN produk P ON F.id_produk = P.pr_id
WHERE user.id = 1
```

But play around with some of my other example queries.  They may be more helpful.